# Good Hopkins score but poor clustering quality

Tags: pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

Before performing clustering, I used the Hopkins score from pyclustertend to get an idea about potential for cluster formation. The result of this was 0.049, suggesting the data is suitable for clusetering.

Yet, after clusetering, cluster quality assessed by silhouette score was not impressive (0.37).

As I understand it, this seems quite contradictory. If hopkins is low, I would expect higher silhouette score.

Am I misunderstanding this? Is this suggestive of something going wrong with the clustering process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I havent used the module before, so this might not be totally correct.

A low hopkins score indicate good potential clustering and in theory, should give a higher silhouette score too. Had to do some digging, but apparently, the silhouette score measures how similar an object is to its own cluster vs others.

I suspect that based on the apparently contradictory information might be the result of the number of clusters. It might be that certain objects being close to multiple clusters. Try changing the number of clusters. See how that changes your silhouette score for those objects. Or see how the silhouette score is for the majority of other objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! As is standard with clustering, I ran a range of potential k values and chose the best based on the elbow method. Initially, this was three. When I tried again with 2, the silhouette value went up drastically. However, if two clusters really was better than three, then that would also be somewhat contradictory according to the elbow method...

Comment: No worries! I suppose they are all different pieces of evidence for how good the clustering is. For what it's worth, the elbow method is sort of a heuristic, so maybe it's ok that they aren't perfectly consistent. Out of curiosity, what does the elbow plot look like?

Comment: It seems I can't post a picture as a comment. But I'm fairly confident in my elbow reading ability, and certainly to distinguish between 2 and 3 in this scenario; te cost of 2 compared to 3 is much higher, with a fairly clear plateau beginning between 3 and 4